# Launching Geb tests from Intellij

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, spock, geb

I am a long time Eclipse / GGTS user trying to make the transition to Intellij. I'm gradually getting used to it, however one of the things I miss about GGTS was the ability to launch Geb tests from with the IDE very quickly.

When I try to launch a Geb test (pointing at an already-running grails instance on localhost) from Intellij, the entire Grails stack unnecessarily fires up (it looks like `test-app MySpec` is being called). This means that I need to wait about 3 or 4 minutes before my spec even starts running.

Is there a way to launch Geb tests within Intellij without starting up Grails?

Comment: "Is there a way to launch Geb tests within Intellij without starting up Grails?" - You can do things to manage the issue, like connecting to an existing Grails but the answer to the question as asked is no.  An instance of the app has to be initialized in order for your functional tests to have something to communicate with.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I want to launch my Geb test and point it at an already-running grails instance running on localhost. I've updated my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-baseUrl` option when you run your tests.

Create a new Grails Run configuration in IDEA that looks something like this:

```
test-app functional: -baseUrl=http://localhost:8080/
```

Then your Geb tests will connect to the grails instance running on `localhost:8080` instead of creating their own instance.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give this a try